# Why they doesn't consider intersection of perticular order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I was reading this, question (shown in pic). But I didn't get, in (3) why they doesn't consider case of $|Q_i ∩ Q_j| = 9$ ?

Since,  $Q_i ∩ Q_j ≤ Q_i$

$→ |Q_i ∩ Q_j| = 9$ is also valid case and if $|Q_i ∩ Q_j| = 9$ then what happens?

[image: first page of proof]

[image: second page of proof.]

Answer (score 1):

If $|Q_i\cap Q_j|=9$, then $Q_i=Q_j$ (and so $i=j$), since $|Q_i|=|Q_j|=9$.  Since the cases (a) and (b) in the argument are based on the intersections $Q_i\cap Q_j$ for $i\neq j$, this possibility is thus irrelevant.

Comment: How $Q_i = Q_j$ ? Since there are two groups of order 9 upto isomorphism. Order are equal doesn't mean groups are equal?

Comment: Well, $Q_i=Q_i\cap Q_j=Q_j$, since $Q_i\cap Q_j$ contains all $9$ elements of both of them...

Comment: Yes. Thanks sir. but if "$Q_i = Q_j$ then what? How the possibility of 9 discarded?

Comment: Thanks sir got it..