# The cases in proving that a group of order 90 is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

[image: Problem]

I am trying to attempt this problem, but I am wondering why exactly these are the two cases the problem is split into. I can understand the first case, since that lets us count elements and get a contradiction, but why is the second case there? In other words, why do these two cases exhaust all possibilities?

Comment: Slightly different context, but essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536201/why-they-doesnt-consider-intersection-of-perticular-order

Comment: Of course they are exhaustive: (b) is the negation of (a). If two different subgroups of order 9 do not intersect trivially, then they necessarily intersect in a 3-element subgroup, as a proper nontrivial subgroup in a 9-element group must have 3 elements by the Lagrange theorem.